# How can I view my ASP.net website on mobile devices

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, mobile

I am developing ASP.Net application which I will later upload/host it. I have being thinking or wondering on how can I access my website on the phone or any mobile device as this is preferable this days.

This is my first time wanted to be able to access my application on mobile device, just like any website that you can check/view using your mobile device.

Can anyone guide me on how I can do this or any tutorial that will help me.

Comment: Asp.net is a web technics that is running on an Internet Information Server. Have you installed it and are your mobile device able to join into you local (wlan) network?

Comment: for now am running my application on test mode. using local host. i want to know what is need so that it can work

Comment: Put your mobile device in your lan and then type http://<ip adresse of the host computer>/<name of the website> into adress bar from browser on your mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS set up on your dev machine, you can publish your project to IIS. Then you should be able to get to your site by specifying in the URL your PC followed by the port. Your phone/tablet will have to be on the same network as your computer, so that it can find it locally.

```
MyComputer:9000/
```

Take a look at this Tutorial

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying to Test](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

**On another Note**

If you use Google Chrome you can emulate the site on a Mobile Device. Other Browsers may offer this too.

See this Tutorial Below

[Device Mode & Mobile Emulation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)

Comment: emulating the site on mobile does not really work 100%. simply because part of testing on real devices is checking JavaScript which the desktop browser does not do.

Answer (score 0):

IN you master page add something like

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Firefox has responsive design mode.

With Responsive Design Mode enabled, the content area for web pages is set to the screen size for the particular device.

Initially, it's set to 320 x 480 pixels

There are three ways to toggle Responsive Design Mode:

- From the Firefox menu: select "Responsive Design Mode" from the Web Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display the menu bar or are on OS X).
- From the Developer Tools toolbox: press the "Responsive Design Mode" button in the Toolbox's toolbar
- From the keyboard: press Ctrl + Shift + M, (or Cmd + Opt + M on OS X).

For more details [Responsive Design in Firfox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode)

Comment: emulating the site on mobile does not really work 100%. simply because part of testing on real devices is checking JavaScript which the desktop browser does not do.